# for loop with nested while loop - Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]

a = 0
i = 0
for i in lst:
    while a < len(lst):
        a += 1
        print(a, i)
```

And I'd like it to print

```
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
1 2
2 2
3 2
4 2
1 3
2 3
3 3
4 3
1 4
2 4
3 4
4 4
```

However, I am struggling to achieve this. I can only get it to print the first item in the list.

```
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Move the initialization of a to inside the first loop, so that it gets reset to 0 on every iteration.

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]

i = 0
for i in lst:
    a = 0
    while a < len(lst):
        a += 1
        print(a, i)
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to revert `a` to zero after the while loop is completed

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]

a = 0
i = 0
for i in last:
    while a < len(last):
        a += 1
        print(a, I)
    a = 0 # <-- add this
```